# xsd pattern restriction - disallow backslash

Tags: regex, validation, xsd

I have a requirement to disallow backslash characters in a given string field defined by an xsd document.  However, being as green as I am, I am not confident with my xsd and/or regex knowledge.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<xs:simpleType name="BackslashRestrictedField">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="0" />
    <xs:pattern value="[^\\]"/> <!-- disallow backslash '\' char ??? -->
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, with this expression, you only allow a string that's one character long and that won't accept backslash. Adding a * at the end of your regexp should fix this issue.